# RewriteRule to change a url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I want to change a url with RewriteRule, like this

http://www.myweb.com/camisetas/something.html

to

http://www.myweb.com/catalogo/something.html

something.html is variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^camisetas/(.+)$ /catalogo/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this in your .htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine ON`

`RewriteRule ^/camisetas/(.*)$ http://www.myweb.com/catalogo/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Many thanks it works fine, I remove / from camisetas